# LAMP server image permissions

Tags: permissions, lamp, images

This is probably a simple question, we have an Ubuntu (10.04) LAMP server running a website created with iWeb. Images uploaded by iWeb are viewable, but images uploaded via ftp to the site with universal read/execute permissions do not appear. When I go to the URL of the image itself, however, the image shows up fine. We used to use a different server, on which the images showed up without a problem...

Is there still some kind of permissions error?

Thanks,
mindoftea

Answer (score 0):

Read error apache log to identify problems.

Comment: I'll look it up next time I can access the server. Meanwhile, it doesn't seem to be an error with Apache exactly; here is the page: http://www.louisvilleclassicalacademy.org/Louisville_Classical_Academy/Campus.html, the image should appear in the upper right corner, but doesn't. Here is the image itself: http://www.louisvilleclassicalacademy.org/Louisville_Classical_Academy/slideshowcampus/photo1.png.

Comment: <img src="..../photo1.png" ..> src is HTML document! In img tag, src attribute point to image. Image url: http://68.16.191.225/slideshowcampus/photo2.png.

Comment: There are two images,  photo1.png and photo2.png, in the same place. Other than that, I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Who is the owner of the file?  Try changing it... `chown nobody:ftp photo1.png`

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow when I get the chance.

Comment: Hmmm... It didn't work... Thanks though!